# Quickly mapping values from one pandas dataframe to another with datetime conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance

I have two dataframes

```
df1=

ID Value BeginDate EndDate  
1  0.5   1/1/12    1/1/13  
1  0.6   1/1/13    1/1/14  
2  0.4   1/1/12    1/1/13  
3  0.7   1/1/12    1/1/13

df2=
ID Date  
1  6/6/12  
1  7/5/12   
1  10/5/13  
2  8/9/12 
3  6/6/12
```

I want to map the Value column from `df1` onto `df2` based on the ID column and whether the `Date` column in `df2` fits between `BeginDate` and `EndDate` in `df1`. The problem is that `df1` has 10,000 rows and `df2` has 1,000,000 rows.

I know that this is possible. I am mostly concerned with how to do this quickly.

I've had to do something similar before where `df1` only has 10 rows, and I used `df1.iterrows` like so

```
df2['Value'] = 1  
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    df1['Value'] = np.where(
                  (row['BeginDate'] <= df2['Date']) 
                & (df2['Date'] <= row['EndDate']),  
                row['Value'],  
                df2['Value'])
```

However, obviously with `df1` now having 10,000 rows, `iterrows` is no longer preferable.

I've considered defining a function and using `df2.apply`, but this would involve filtering `df1` on every iteration. I've had efficiency problems with this approach in the past.

It's possible to break up df1 into smaller dataframes based on another column (not displayed in example). So instead of one big dataframe, I'll have 10 smaller ones. I'm thinking of putting them into a dictionary. The keys of this dictionary can be mapped from `df2`, so this would help, but still leaves me with my initial question.

I've seen approaches using a mask and `df.loc`, but haven't figured out a way with the date conditions.

Doing this using `pandas` isn't essential.

Comment: i expect that you would use `merge` with some rules.  like this `merged_df = pd.merge(df1, df2, on="ID")`....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the intervals are non overlapping, the most efficient pandas approach would be to [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) on the BeginDate, then to check that the EndDate is valid:

```
df1[['BeginDate', 'EndDate']] = df1[['BeginDate', 'EndDate']].apply(pd.to_datetime, format='%d/%m/%y')
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'], format='%d/%m/%y')


out = (pd.merge_asof(
 df2.reset_index()
    .sort_values(by='Date'),
 df1.sort_values(by='BeginDate'),
    left_on='Date', right_on='BeginDate', by='ID')
    .assign(Value=lambda d: d['Value'].where(d['Date'].le(d['EndDate'])))
    .set_index('index').sort_index()
)
```

Output (with all columns, you can then drop the BeginDate/EndDate):

```
       ID       Date  Value  BeginDate    EndDate
index                                            
0       1 2012-06-06    0.5 2012-01-01 2013-01-01
1       1 2012-05-07    0.5 2012-01-01 2013-01-01
2       1 2013-05-10    0.6 2013-01-01 2014-01-01
3       2 2012-09-08    0.4 2012-01-01 2013-01-01
4       3 2012-06-06    0.7 2012-01-01 2013-01-01
```

Alternatively, a more generic method that also handles overlapping intervals would be to use [`janitor`](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.conditional_join.conditional_join);

```
# pip install janitor
import janitor

df1[['BeginDate', 'EndDate']] = df1[['BeginDate', 'EndDate']].apply(pd.to_datetime, format='%d/%m/%y')
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'], format='%d/%m/%y')

df2.conditional_join(df1,
                     ('ID', 'ID', '=='),
                     ('Date', 'BeginDate', '>='),
                     ('Date', 'EndDate', '<='),
                     )
```

Answer (score 0):

There's really no need for `iterrows`, you can use `np.where` efficiently without `iterrows` by passing the `Series` as a whole:

```
def broadcast_approach(df1, df2):
    df2['Value'] = 1
    df1['Value'] = np.where(
                  (df1['BeginDate'] <= df2['Date'])
                & (df2['Date'] <= df1['EndDate']),
                df1['Value'],
                df2['Value'])
```

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [1, 1, 2, 3],
    'Value': [0.5, 0.6, 0.4, 0.7],
    'BeginDate': ['1/1/12', '1/1/13', '1/1/12', '1/1/12'],
    'EndDate': ['1/1/13', '1/1/14', '1/1/13', '1/1/13']
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [ 1, 1, 2, 3],
    'Date': [ '7/5/12', '10/5/13', '8/9/12', '1/1/12']
})
```

```
>>> broadcast_approach(df1, df2)
>>> print(df1)

ID  Value   BeginDate   EndDate
0   1   1.0 1/1/12  1/1/13
1   1   1.0 1/1/13  1/1/14
2   2   1.0 1/1/12  1/1/13
3   3   0.7 1/1/12  1/1/13
```

For performance comparison some benchmarking:

```
import timeit
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def iterrow_approach(df1, df2):
    df2['Value'] = 1
    for index, row in df1.iterrows():
        df1['Value'] = np.where(
                      (row['BeginDate'] <= df2['Date'])
                    & (df2['Date'] <= row['EndDate']),
                    row['Value'],
                    df2['Value'])

def broadcast_approach(df1, df2):
    df2['Value'] = 1
    df1['Value'] = np.where(
                  (df1['BeginDate'] <= df2['Date'])
                & (df2['Date'] <= df1['EndDate']),
                df1['Value'],
                df2['Value'])

dataset_sizes = [100, 1000, 10000, 50000]

iterrow_times = []
broadcast_times = []

for size in dataset_sizes:
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({
        'ID': np.random.randint(1, 10, size=size),
        'Value': np.random.rand(size),
        'BeginDate': pd.date_range('1/1/2012', periods=size).strftime('%m/%d/%y'),
        'EndDate': pd.date_range('1/1/2013', periods=size).strftime('%m/%d/%y')
    })

    df2 = pd.DataFrame({
        'ID': np.random.randint(1, 10, size=size),
        'Date': pd.date_range('1/1/2012', periods=size).strftime('%m/%d/%y')
    })

    iterrow_time = timeit.timeit(lambda: iterrow_approach(df1.copy(), df2.copy()), number=1)
    broadcast_time = timeit.timeit(lambda: broadcast_approach(df1.copy(), df2.copy()), number=1)
    iterrow_times.append(iterrow_time)
    broadcast_times.append(broadcast_time)

plt.plot(dataset_sizes, iterrow_times, label='iterrow_approach')
plt.plot(dataset_sizes, broadcast_times, label='broadcast_approach')
plt.xlabel('Dataset Size')
plt.ylabel('Execution Time (seconds)')
plt.title('Performance Comparison')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: If you have many rows within an ID the combinations might explode quickly. You should use a log scale on your graph to appreciate the real timing of the numpy approach.

Comment: Thanks for your response, just playing around with it now. Am I mistaken in saying that this approach only works when the dataframes have the same number of rows?

Answer (score 0):

Is it feasible to merge the data from df1 into df2, then to use logic on two columns in the new dataframe?

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'ID': [1, 1, 2, 3],
        'Value': [0.5, 0.6, 0.4, 0.7],
        'BeginDate': ['1/1/12', '1/1/13', '1/1/12', '1/1/12'],
        'EndDate': ['1/1/13', '1/1/14', '1/1/13', '1/1/13']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

data = {'ID': [1, 1, 1, 2, 3], 
        'Date': ['6/6/12', '7/5/12', '10/5/13', '8/9/12', '6/6/12']}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)

merged_df=pd.merge(df2, df1, how='left', left_on=['ID'], right_on=['ID'])
```

Then merged_df looks like

```
ID  Date    Value   BeginDate   EndDate
1   6/6/12  0.5 1/1/12  1/1/13
1   6/6/12  0.6 1/1/13  1/1/14
1   7/5/12  0.5 1/1/12  1/1/13
1   7/5/12  0.6 1/1/13  1/1/14
1   10/5/13 0.5 1/1/12  1/1/13
1   10/5/13 0.6 1/1/13  1/1/14
2   8/9/12  0.4 1/1/12  1/1/13
3   6/6/12  0.7 1/1/12  1/1/13
```

and

```
merged_df['BeginDate'] < merged_df['Date']
```

returns

```
0    True
1    True
2    True
3    True
4    True
5    True
6    True
7    True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: This is however inefficient as you will compute all combinations of rows per ID, imagine 100 rows for ID 1 in each input, the intermediate will have 10k rows.